# SpellCheck in WinForms WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, spell-checking

We are wanting to add spell-check to a website hosted in our application via the WebBrowser control.

If you open our sites in a newer browser like IE9, etc. spellchecking already works in the browser by default.

Is there a way to get this working in the WinForms WebBrowser control?

EDIT: what about making it work in the Frame control in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spell checking with IE 11 or Edge is working on Web Browser control and Windows 10 now. I have managed to make it work on a contenteditable body:

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in Document.All)
        {
            el.SetAttribute("unselectable", "on");
            el.SetAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
        }
        Document.Body.SetAttribute("width", Width.ToString() + "px");
        Document.Body.SetAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        Document.Body.SetAttribute("spellcheck", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning on trying it myself but [IESpell](http://www.iespell.com) looks like a good client side solution. Should work since the WebBrowser control uses IE under the hood.

EDIT: I had trouble getting IESpell working in the WebBrowser control so I went looking for an html editor and found [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) and another [article](http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2008/05/09/tinyMCE-running-in-Windows-Forms.aspx) to use it in WinForms. TinyMCE has a spell check feature.

Comment: I'll look into this, I'll mark you as the answer if it seems like it will work for us.

Comment: I don't think this is a good option for us.  We are wanting a solution that is not in HTML, or a solution at the browser level.  We are hosting an intranet site in the WebBrowser control that is quite large, and were looking for a quick solution to not require changes server side.  I'm going to leave this question up a little while, but I believe there isn't a good solution for it.